# Override pyreadline output on Windows

Tags: python, readline

Is there a way to edit custom pyreadline complete options. For example if I have a complete function which returns the following matches:

```
shell>ap<TAB>
apple apricot
```

I want to edit the output to look like this instead:

```
shell>ap<TAB>
apple - green fruit with seeds
apricot - orange fruit with stone
```

I know in Linux this is possible using the set_completion_display_matches_hook method. However on Windows this method is not available. Anybody know of Windows solution?